# Htaccess rewrite with id

Tags: php, .htaccess

i got a problem with rewriting my `edit.php?id=1` to `edit/id/1`. Right now i have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^edit/id/([^/.]+)$ edit.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

This doesn't change the url. Can something see what i do wrong?

Comment: Do you want it to redirect to the php file?

Comment: I want it to rewrite my url from `edit.php?id=1` to `edit/id/1`

Comment: So what you want to see in the brower bar is `edit/id/1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and see how it works for you.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/edit/id/([^/.]+)$ $1/edit.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
   </IfModule>
```

OR you can do this if you only have a couple of directories the same. The will go in the root .htaccess file.

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(profiles|customers|test)/edit/id/([^/.]+)$ $1/edit.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
       </IfModule>
```

Comment: Give me more info. What error are you getting? What is happening? What result are you expecting. I don't believe it's the code.

Comment: Nothing is happening. The `edit?id=1` is not rewriting to `edit/id/1`. There are no errors or something like that, and i did put the exact code into my .htaccess file. I navigate to `mywebsite/edit?id=1` shouldn't that rewrite the url to  `mywebsite/edit/id/1` ?

Comment: No that's not how rewrite works. you are supposed to navigate to `mywebsite/edit/id/1` and the server will rewrite to `mywebsite/edit?id=1` in the background. The user will never see `mywebsite/edit?id=1` that is the point of `pretty urls`.

Comment: Just navigated to `mywebsite/edit/id/1` and it gave me 500 internal server error..

Comment: Ok now you need to check your apache error log to see what the error is so you can fix the problem.

Comment: It's hard to find the apache error log when you are on a host, so would be nice with a way that works 100%

Comment: The only way to find out what is happening for sure is to know what's causing the error.  Maybe you don't have mod_rewrite enabled. Check my edited code. I will put a condition check. Let me know if you still get the 500 error when accessing `mysite/edit/id/1

Comment: I still get the error. Mod_rewrite should be on, because i removed the extension tags earlier..

Comment: The test link you provided in the other answer shows it's in `/test` that makes a big difference whether this rule will work properly. Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: The file is in the root folder ../test

Comment: So your url in the browser should be like `mysite.com/test/edit/id/1`

Comment: If you want to keep the .htaccess file in the root directory, the edited code above should work. If you have customer/edit profile/edit test/edit, it will be dynamic and work for any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need one additional rule to change the URL externally. **This should be placed in root .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]+)/edit\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/edit/id/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/edit/id/([^/.]+)$ $1/edit.php?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This should rewrite it automatic right? but it isn't

Comment: Here is the testing url: [link](http://michaeldk.esy.es/test/edit.php?id=1), and my .htaccess is copy paste from ours.

Comment: That worked! So how should i do this when i got other folders like: profile/edit.. customer/edit etc.