# .htaccess Rewrite - Masking Dynamic .php extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic, url-rewriting

I understand that similar questions have been asked before in regard to .htaccess, but after hours of reading through the Questions, Answers and Comments, as well as countless hours reading .htaccess documentation and even trying .htaccess generators... and messing my site access up via trying examples... I come to seek those wiser than me for guidance.

I am using the following .htaccess file to remove .php extensions from URLS shown to the user in the browser

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

> This works perfectly
> **[www.example.com/users/player.php?id=1](http://www.example.com/users/player.php?id=1)** is being correctly shown as
> **[www.example.com/users/player?id=1](http://www.example.com/users/player?id=1)**

I am now struggling to write/find/understand examples that will allow me to rewrite the full extension

> I want to show
> **[www.example.com/users/player.php?id=1](http://www.example.com/users/player.php?id=1)**
> as
> **[www.example.com/users/1](http://www.example.com/users/1)**
> totally removing the **player.php?id=** part of the dynamic URL

Thank you in advance for any help/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who wants to do what I wanted to do, I have found a solution.

Question: [Htaccess rewrite with id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221377/htaccess-rewrite-with-id)

Answer: [from Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)

This will allow you to externally mask "edit.php?id=1" to "edit/id/1" as well as use either URL interchangeably.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]+)/edit\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/edit/id/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/edit/id/([^/.]+)$ $1/edit.php?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Best of luck!